# How do I match multiple number of digits using [:digit:] in grep?

Tags: grep

I am for the first time using grep and after reading the manual I decide to use [:digit:] instead of \d or [0-9] for matching numbers. I found out that in grep, it is actually [[:digit:]] that matches numbers. While I managed to understand why there are double brackets, I cannot figure out a way to match with multiple integers.

```
echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]'
```

will print (as expected):

```
1
0
0
```

But if I try

```
echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]+'
```

or

```
echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]{0,3}'
```

or

```
echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+'
echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{0,3\}'
```

It will fail to match anything. Why?

Comment: What OS / what implementation of grep are you using?

Comment: Some of your examples will work when using GNU `grep`.  Are you on MacOS?  In any case, just add the `-E` option and then `echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]+'` and `echo 'i100s'|grep -o '[[:digit:]]{0,3}'` should work on any platform.

Comment: It is CentOS. Adding -E option will make it work. It's quite interesting to know that -E is not necessary for GNU grep to understand the '+' sign

Answer (score 5):

The + operator was an innovation after the very oldest version of grep. Prior to that, you had to express + as a single instance followed by the same instance with a *. Not too elegant. Clearly the range operator is also in the same category. You'll run into the same problem on Vim when doing a search, unless you preface it with a \v (the vim equivalent of -E).

So as John1024 points out, on a Mac,

```
$echo 'i100s'| grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+'
100
$echo 'i100s'| egrep -o '[[:digit:]]+'
100
```

The documentation for gnu grep (which is available on the Mac through homebrew or other package managers) says its default behavior is -F (assumes basic regular expression), but like john1024 says, my experience is that it supports the advanced expressions without using -E or the `egrep` variant. If you install gnu grep with homebrew, it helpfully installs it as `ggrep`, so that if there is some incompatibility between say script behaviors using the Mac's `grep` and `ggrep`, you can resolve it by changing symbolic links from one executable to the other.

Comment: `-F` is for fixed string. The default in any `grep` implementation including GNU `grep` is BRE (`-G` in GNU `grep`, like `-o` not a standard option) not `-F`. `[[:digit:]]+` is standard in ERE, the standard equivalent for BRE in `[[:digit:]]\{1,\}`. `[[:digit:]]{1,}` is also standard in `grep -E`, but wont work in the original `egrep` (and still in some current `egrep` implementation like on Solaris; `egrep` is not a standardized command).

Comment: The -E extension is needed in order to match for 100 in my case. Likely it is due to the version of my OS...

Comment: Yeah, Stéphane makes a good point. I was unaware that `egrep` is a moving target in terms of portability so `grep -E` seems more reliable. But overall, the problem is simply that you need something beyond the original `grep` reg-ex language to use even features as common as the '+' operator, let alone some of the others you tried. Nothing wrong with your expressions. You just needed to let `grep` know that you were going to use a more modern set of operators.